# Count number of times a value occurs in a case statement

Tags: mysql

I've looked all over the site for counting the number of times a value occurs in a query and found answers but nothing addressing it in a case statement.

here is the query I am using that returns results but the results should be higher...the results are in the 70's but should be double that number.

query:

```
select count(case when field#1 like "Y" then "1" else null end) as column name
from db
where datefield like '2015-04%'
```

Comment: `select sum(field1 = 'y')`. mysql will convert the boolean true/false result to 0/1 and sum up the 1's.

Comment: count should be just fine. The problem can be the comparison. Either you have a case sensitive collation or you have extra space in your field.

Comment: Are you still working to figure this one out?

Comment: McAdam3312...yes, that worked like a charm - very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish something like this, it's more helpful to use conditional aggregation.

This means, instead of using a case statement to sum items, you just put the condition in the SUM() function:

```
SELECT SUM(field1 LIKE '%y%')'
...
```

If you don't want to use the conditional aggregation approach, and prefer to use `CASE`, you'll need to use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()` like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN field1 LIKE '%y%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS counts
...
```

Comment: All, simple solution and the results are what they are...very much appreciated!

Comment: @benjo glad I could help. If this is the solution you use, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer to let future readers know what solved your problem.

Comment: Both of the examples are "conditional aggregation". The latter example just uses ANSI compliant syntax; it's still returning a 1 or a 0. (There's one slight difference, which we'd observe if all rows had a `field1` value of NULL... the first example would return NULL, the second example would return 0... we could tweak the `CASE` expression so that the return would be the same.) The approach in OP original query is also "conditional aggregation". It would achieve the same result. The real difference in this answer is the use of wildcards in the LIKE comparison.